# JS Destructuring Default Value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, destructuring

I need to write a test that tests a line of code similar to this:

```
const [a, [[b]] = []] = [someValue, someArray];
```

The problem is that I am able to only partially cover this line because I couldn't find a way to trigger default value for `[[b]]`. I'm wondering what should be passed as `someArray` for default value to be used.

I tried the following:

```
undefined //produces an error
[] //produces an error
[[]] //b gets destructured as undefined
[[undefined]] //b gets destructured as undefined
```

Comment: What are you expecting b's default value to be?

Comment: It looks to me like it should default to `undefined`, since the default value doesn't provide a value for it.

Comment: I don't expect it to be anything. This is a line from a legacy code written by another dev. We need to cover it with tests. We are not allowed to change the original code, but we need to make sure we have 100% test coverage. 

To do so in my test I need to write a code that runs this line in both possible ways: when b is properly destructured from someArray and when the default value assignment takes place. I cannot get the second one to occur.

Comment: Since the default value doesn't contain a value for `b`, the cases where it gets destructured as `undefined` are valid values and the expected result.

Comment: Yes. But I am still getting this line as partially covered in jest coverage report because default value assignment in destructuring clause never happened.

Comment: The default value *is* being assigned. The default is `undefined`.

Comment: No, in this case `undefiend` is whatever got extracted from `someArray`, jest marks the line as partially covered becuase `= []` assignment never occured. My question is, how do I get this assignment to occur.

Comment: I think the problem is that the default value is not valid. `b` is supposed to be nested 2-levels deep, but the default value is not nested arrays.

Comment: It should be something like `const [a, [[b]] = [[defaultVal]]]`

Comment: well, in this case just default destructuring happens and `b` gets assigned `defaultVal` and the case when `=[]` is getting assigned still remains uncovered.

Comment: My point is that you can't cover that case, because it requires that the value for `b` be nested in 2 arrays.

Comment: A single array level doesn't match the destructuring pattern.